# How can I output to file the result from foreach?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I have this script to trim leading spaces, remove " and , from a txt file.
But I couldn't put into an output file the result

```
$text = Get-Content output.txt
$text -replace '["]','' -replace '[,]','' | Foreach {write-host $_.TrimStart()}
```

This is the result I'm getting. I wanted it to output on a file instead of showing like this.

```
PS C:\Users\aa1\temp> $text -replace '["]','' -replace '[,]','' | Foreach {write-host $_.TrimStart()}
AutoScalingGroupName: asg1
MinSize: 1
AutoScalingGroupName: asg2
MinSize: 1
AutoScalingGroupName: asg3
MinSize: 1
AutoScalingGroupName: asg4
MinSize: 1
AutoScalingGroupName: asg5
MinSize: 3
PS C:\Users\aa1\temp>
```

Comment: A file is not the host. So remove `Write-Host` because that is literally what it’s made for, strictly writing to host (the application you’re running the command in, powershell)

Answer (score 1):

If you read the contents of the file as one multiline string using parameter `-Raw` instead of a string array, you can do all replacements without using a loop like this:

```
(Get-Content -Path 'output.txt' -Raw) -replace '(?m)[",]|^\s+' | Set-Content -Path 'output.txt'
```

Regex details:

```
             Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
   (?        Use these options for the whole regular expression
      m      ^$ match at line breaks
   )        
   [",]      Match a single character from the list “",”
|           
             Or match this alternative (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match)
   ^         Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed)
   \s        Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
      +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```